# Incorrect sprite graphic is assigned to tiles

Tags: java, swing, 2d, sprite, tile

I'm now following a series of video tutorials on YouTube, to be specific a Game Programming tutorial by TheChernoProject. I got to episode 36, which is about rendering a level from tiles. I won't get into too much detail on that, but I encountered a strange problem that no one has encountered (at least no one asked for help with it).
To be more precise: I have a Sprite class, a Tile class (with two classes extending it: GrassTile and VoidTile) and a Level class. Level cosists of Tiles, which are made of sprite. You can see the tile here:

```
public static Tile grass = new GrassTile(Sprite.grass);
public static Tile voidTile = new VoidTile(Sprite.voidSprite);
```

And the sprite is created like that:

```
public static Sprite grass = new Sprite(16, 0, 0, Spritesheet.tileset);
public static Sprite voidSprite = new Sprite(16, 0x00AAFF);
```

Two constructors for sprites: these are

```
(int size, int x, int y, Spritesheet sheet)
(int size, int colour)
```

And the level is randomly generated with fields ranging from 0-3 (0 is grass, the rest is currently just VoidTile. But something is wrong with the way it displays graphics. I did check it with the use of printlns, and I'm sure most of it works (it does assign correct Tiles, depending on ID). You can see it there:

```
ID: 0 |   Tile: com.ekhart.game.level.tile.GrassTile@73d74138 |   Sprite: com.ekhart.game.gfx.Sprite@3d0c51ef
ID: 2 |   Tile: com.ekhart.game.level.tile.VoidTile@3ba0d916 |   Sprite: com.ekhart.game.gfx.Sprite@3d0c51ef
ID: 3 |   Tile: com.ekhart.game.level.tile.VoidTile@3ba0d916 |   Sprite: com.ekhart.game.gfx.Sprite@3d0c51ef
ID: 1 |   Tile: com.ekhart.game.level.tile.VoidTile@3ba0d916 |   Sprite: com.ekhart.game.gfx.Sprite@3d0c51ef
```

And you might notice, that the Sprite is the same, even though when I create the grass and voidTile classes, they have different sprites assigned to them. And the weird part is that the sprite assigned depends on the order in which I create them. Now all tiles have a voidSprite graphic, because I created VoidTile last. When I swap them around (making GrassTile last), they all have grass sprite. I tried everything I could think of to make this work, but it doesn't. I have uploaded the project folder, so you can import it and check the code, maybe I've missed something.

Project url: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18909657/TheGame.rar

Comment: this might be a better question for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: You need to do some more debugging at least to isolate the code at fault, and then post it. No one here is going to go through a massive rar file. Voting to close. Check to make sure that you're not using static inappropriately, that you're creating new sprite objects where necessary in loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I lied and did look at your rar file, and you **are** using static inappropriately as I suspected:

```
public class Tile {

public int x;
public int y;

public static Sprite sprite;

public static Tile grass = new GrassTile(Sprite.grass);
public static Tile voidTile = new VoidTile(Sprite.voidSprite);

public Tile(Sprite sprite) {
    Tile.sprite = sprite;
}

public void render(int x, int y, Screen screen) {
}

public boolean solid() {
    return false;
}

}
```

By making the sprite field static, it is the now the same for all Tile instances.

Solution:

- don't use static inappropriately. The sprite Sprite variable should not be static.
- Do post appropriate code on this site so we don't have to do the scut work for you that you should be doing yourself, such as digging for the error.
- Don't mix AWT and Swing components unnecessarily.

Note that if your compile complains at you when you change sprite to be non-static, then you must fix the other code that uses the sprite field, not make sprite static again.